# Cannot find a file in Visual Studio

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to customize the Business Logic(SPCaseNewEntry.cs) for NewCase Screen(SP203000) on portal. I opened the project in visual studio but cannot find the SPCaseNewEntry.cs file under CodeRepository. Can Anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***SPCaseNewEntry*** BLC is declared within *SP.Objects.dll*, which is used exclusively by Acumatica Self-Service Portal. Currently, in **CodeRepository** there is only source code of *PX.Objects.dll* (contains all classes used in Acumatica ERP) and core classes and attributes from *PX.Data.dll*.

Comment: Is there a way I can see the source code of SP.Objects.dll?

Comment: Unfortunately, Acumatica does not share the code of SP.Objects.dll